# Copy paste key bindings not working in Tilda Terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tilda

In the Gnome terminal or in the terminator, I use Ctrl+Shift+C for copying and Ctrl+Shift+V for pasting, but these key bindings are not working in Tilda. I checked them in the preferences of tilda, and it is the same keybinding.

Other shortcuts like opening new tab(Ctrl+Shift+T), closing tabsCtrl+Shift+W), quitting the application(Ctrl+Shift+Q) are all working fine. What to do to make copy paste key bindings work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (linux mint 17.2) and when I changed the settings (Prefrences/scrolling) to have the scroll bar to the right(or disabled) it worked, but it doesn't work with the scrollbar to the left for some reason. .

Also other keybinding for copy and pasting don't seem to work regardless.

Seems to be a random bug.

UPDATE: it should have been fixed in recent versions